# Why is_atom(nil) equals to true in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Pretty simple question, I noted it when worked on [exfile](https://github.com/keichan34/exfile/pull/39) library.

This expression returns:

```
is_atom(nil) # => true
```

It's kinda unpredictable. My question is: how it's happened? Why it returns  `true`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nil` is an atom, along with `true` and `false`.

This is documented for `true` and `false` in http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#atoms

You can also check with:

```
nil == :nil
true == :true
false == :false
```

Some relevant links:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.2/lib/elixir/src/elixir_tokenizer.erl#L986
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.2/lib/elixir/src/elixir_parser.yrl#L253

Comment: Hm, kinda strange solution. But my name isn't a Jose Valim. Why he did it, how do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure, `true` and `false` are atoms in Erlang, so that is a likely influence http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id76595. It was added in this commit https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/0054df323420def2797152f16845798d4846b634

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is because "nil" is an atom, just like "true" or "false".